# Можно ли вносить изменения в файл html не заходя на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть сайт pta-ua.com. Там есть раздел рейтинг, в котором регулярно меняются значения. В данный момент я меняю все данные на компьютере и перезаливаю весь файл index.html на сервер через FTP. Можно ли как-то проще это сделать? Может есть какой-то простой шаблон админки, куда можно выводить все значения и редактировать их в окне браузера? Подcкажите, какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Да, редактировать эти файлы можно и нужно. В Вашем случае выберите какой-нибудь популярный движок, типа Wordpress или Drupal (который потом будет просто поддерживать).

Comment: спасибо, я знаю что есть такой вариант, просто для меня интеграция на движок не самый приятный процесс, тем более сайт легкий и там всего лишь рейтинг нужно менять и дату ближайшого события. Я подумал, что проще будет свою админку вывести. Типа создать файл admin.php и вывести туда такую же таблицу, но с возможностью редактировать значения.

Comment: тогда да, если один файл - просто напишите скрипт, который будет менять ваш html-файл по запросу.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать и использовать админку(backend.php включив sql и все что вам надо) для этого.
Вы можете использовать для этого git. Здесь (https://habrahabr.ru/post/127213/) очень простой вариант. Git + IDE, которая поддерживает git